# Formatting the scientific notation phone number in python

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, data-cleaning, phone-number

I have my phone_number column listed below.

```
phone_number
--------------
001 1234567890
380 1234567890
 27 1234567890
001 +11234567890
2.56898E+11
1 1234567890
123-456-7890
 +1 (123) 456-7890
(123) 456-7890
NaN
```

The following step worked fine

```
character = '[^0-9]+'
df.phone_number.str.replace(character, '')
```

The result I got is

```
phone_number
--------------
11234567890
3.80123E+12
2.71234E+11
11234567890
2.56898E+11
11234567890
1234567890
11234567890
1234567890
NaN
```

Is there any elegant way to deal with the scientific notation format? I want them to be 11234567890 or longer because of the country code. From there I think I can figure out how to get both international and the US phone number formats. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the column definition/data type for phone_number.

Comment: Scientific notation needs to be converted to fixed format before this data becomes a string.

Comment: @JohnGordon - it shows `object`

Comment: Try this example
[Number with code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/975604/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83)

Comment: Was your data source created in goddamn MSExcel? If yes, go to the original file and fix the column format. Also try to examine that value in scientific notation to check if there are other digits remaining. Most probably they are not, then this number is irrecoverable in dataframe and may be fixed in original source only.

Comment: @SUTerliakov - Yeah, the "excellent" csv!!! Well, I just figured out, no matter how to convert those scientific numbers into numbers, it's not correct. Once I expanded numbers, it has 0s all the way to the end... that's an invalid phone number

Comment: It was valid, when somebody entered it. Excel assumed (how? don't ask) that cell type should be float, thus converting to exponential and (seems that) discarding non-significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conversion to `Int64`/`string` dtypes:

```
s1 = (pd.to_numeric(df['phone_number'], errors='coerce')
        .astype('Int64').astype('string')
      )

s2 = df['phone_number'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)

df['phone_number_clean'] = s1.fillna(s2)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        phone_number phone_number_clean
0     001 1234567890      0011234567890
1     380 1234567890      3801234567890
2      27 1234567890       271234567890
3   001 +11234567890     00111234567890
4        2.56898E+11       256898000000
5       1 1234567890        11234567890
6       123-456-7890         1234567890
7  +1 (123) 456-7890        11234567890
8     (123) 456-7890         1234567890
```

*Note that depending on the float precision and the way the number was converted to scientific notation, you might lose important digits.*